# Can I make this web.config rewrite rule?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

In web.config I would like to set up the following rule for my ASP.NET project:

A request to:

```
mydomain.com/123/some-page
```

returns page

```
mydomain.com/collection/123-some-page.html
```

In other words

```
domain/x/y should fetch and return domain/collection/x-y.html
```

The visitor should still see the domain/x/y in the browser url.

Can I make such a rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to install url rewrite module in IIS
and set below rule in `web.config`

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="My rewrite">
      <match url="^(.*)/(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="collection/{R:1}-{R:2}.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```